# Where is Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management.dll for windows 8?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-assembly, group-policy

I installed **Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 8** from 'http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28972', but there is no **Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management**

I used the instruction from this page. "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx"

I have set the registry key, and I can see all folders. But I can not find it. I have searched my whole system using **Everything** (voidtools.com).

where can I find it ?

Comment: It might not be part of the Windows 8 version of RSAT...you could try opening a cmd prompt and then do a `dir /s %windir%\assembly\Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management*.*` to verify that it is really not there...

Comment: I searched there, but it was not there.

Comment: Maybe you should take a step back, describe what your goal is, show the code you would use to reach that goal on Windows 7/2008 and then ask how that code would port to Windows 8.

Comment: I want to read group policy list from domain controller server and add a new policy to install a software MSI package on clients. after search, I found that the way is to use Group Policy Management Console .

Comment: I found that the **Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 8** is not installed correctly. I tried several times, it says Installation Completed! but it is not in the windows installed updates. Also in Windows Features, Remote Tools is not added. What should I do ?

Comment: Can you try to install the windows 7 version (maybe on a virtual PC running windows 7) from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887)

Comment: I have installed the windows 7, and the tool installed successfully ! but it does not installed on Windows 8. Any Idea ?

Comment: I installed it on Windows 8.1 and it works !!!

Answer (score 0):

On Win8, the Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management.dll is located @

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35